# ValueError: could not convert string to float:While loading data from sql server to Predict()

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using SKLEARN & Pandas to load a dataset for prediction. On training data it's working like a charm , problem comes when.
I am passing data frame to predict function (I am loading this data direct from SQL server). 
**Error :**

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'MESSAGE: Send me an
>   email.\r'

```
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import re
import csv
import pyodbc

server = "{10.66.74.80}"
db = "{SMS}"
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db)

query = "SELECT Prediction,Message from HC_followup where prediction in ('Sat','Dis_Sat')"
df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
df.head()

train_df,test_df=train_test_split(df,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

train_df.loc[train_df['Prediction']=='Dis_Sat','Prediction']=0
train_df.loc[train_df['Prediction']=='Sat','Prediction']=1

X=train_df['Message']
X.head()
train_y=train_df['Prediction'].values
train_y=train_y.astype(np.int)
train_y[:]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vec=CountVectorizer()
count_vec
count_vec.fit(X)
train_x=count_vec.transform(X).toarray()
train_x[:]
train_x.shape

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr_clf=LogisticRegression()
lr_clf
lr_clf.fit(train_x,train_y)
server = "{W10HSVQXX1}"
db = "{test}"
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db)
 query = "select Message from [dbo].[followup] where prediction ='Un-Known'"
df_test = pd.read_sql(query, con)
df_test.head()
cnt=CountVectorizer()
cnt
print(df_test.shape)
res=lr_clf.predict(count_vec.transform(df_test))
print(res)
if res==0:
     print("Customer Is Dis_Sat")
if res==1:
     print("Customer Is Sat")
print("Accuracy Percentage : ",lr_clf.score(train_x,train_y)*100,'%')
```

**Note:** Model has been already trained and fitted.

Open to any advise/opinion. I am new bee to this technology.
Thanks!

Comment: which line is giving you this error?

Comment: @Mohit : res=lr_clf.predict(df_test) 
line is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are directly feeding the text data into the logistic regression model. May you have used CountVectorizer / TfidfVectorizer in-between during training. Use the same vectorizer to do the `transform()`. Then feed the transformed text data into the logistic regression model.

See my suggestion on predict line.

EDIT:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
lr_clf.fit(train_x,train_y) 
server = "{W10HSVQXX1}"
db = "{test}" 
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db) 
query = "select Message from [dbo].[followup] where prediction ='Un-Known'" 
df_test = pd.read_sql(query, con) 
df_test.head() 
len(count_vec.get_feature_names()) 

res=lr_clf.predict(count_vec.transform(df_test))
print(res)
```